# mathematica's equivalent of python list functionnality

Tags: list-manipulation, python

In Python there is a  a compact syntax for creating variables that refer to the various list elements.

```
>>> somelist = [’book.tex’, ’book.log’, ’book.pdf’]
>>> texfile, logfile, pdf = somelist
>>> texfile
’book.tex’
>>> logfile
’book.log’
>>> pdf
’book.pdf’
```

Of course the number of variables on the left-hand side must match the number of elements in the list.
The only relevant I can think in Mathematica is `MapThread` (or `Thread`).

```
In[4]:= somelist = {"book.tex", "book.log", "book.pdf"};
MapThread[Set, {{texfile, logfile, pdf}, somelist}]

Out[5]= {"book.tex", "book.log", "book.pdf"}
```

Is there anything else similar in Mathematica?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, you can do destructuring assignments:

```
someList = {"book.tex", "book.log", "book.pdf"};

{texFile, logFile, pdf} = someList;

texFile
(* "book.tex" *)

pdf 
(* "book.pdf *)
```